# Azure Automation Powershell runbook failed to load assembly

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation

## Code That I am running on azure portal

```
Write-Output "Starting"
$assemblyPath = "C:\Modules\Global\Azure\Compute\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
dir $assemblyPath

Write-Output "1"        
Add-Type -Path $assemblyPath
Write-Output "2"
```

## Output

[image]

## Any idea on this?

Comment: of course it failed, there is no the path if you run from azure portal. You should run it from your local pc which can target the path you specified.

Comment: @IvanYang Means there is no way to do in azure portal

Comment: You can explain more clearly, like after `add-type` cmdlet, what do your want to do next?

Comment: I need to run this through using azure portal. How can I do?

Comment: @IvanYang I want to send the mail using exchange services instead of SMTP

Comment: please use Install-Module -Name EWS, refer this link: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/EWS/1.1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load the `.dll` assembly, you could refer to the steps.

1.Navigate to your automation account in the portal-> Modules -> Add Module, compress the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll` file to `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.zip`, then upload. After uploading, you will find it in the portal.

[image]

2.Change the `$assemblyPath`, your complete command should be as below, it will work fine.

```
Write-Output "Starting"
$assemblyPath = "C:\Modules\User\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll"
dir $assemblyPath

Write-Output "1"        
Add-Type -Path $assemblyPath
Write-Output "2"
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you so much for answer. But I have one more question I want to send mail using exchange services instead of SMTP. I used Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll and it has the function Send-EWSmail but that is not working.                                                                                   '$Credential=Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'ServiceAccount'
Send-EWSmail -to "**@gmail.com" -Subject "Automated mail" -Body "PowerShell and Exchange rock!" -Credential $Credential'    please help me with this as well

Comment: please see above comment again. Please help

Comment: @SumitGarg To use `Send-EWSmail`, just go to `Browse Gallery` and import the module, refer to : https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EJkF.png

Comment: Yeah thanks my issue is resolved. I used Send-EWSmail instead of Send-EWSEmail